# Getting Error-AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors Class.AccountHandler

Tags: apex

//Write a Trigger to Prevent duplication of account record based on name whenever a record is inserted or updated.

```java
public static void DuplicateAccName(list<Account> newlist, map<id,account>oldmap) {
        set<string>accname=new set<string>();
        
        if(!newlist.isempty()){
            for(account acc:newlist){
              accname.add(acc.name);
            }
        }
        list<Account>acclist=[Select id ,name from account where name in:accname];
        map<string,account>newmap=new map<string,account>();
        if(!newlist.isempty()){
            for(account acct:acclist){
               newmap.put(acct.name,acct); 
                if(newmap.containskey(acct.name)){
                    acct.adderror('Sorry Name already present');
                  
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Trigger:

```java
if(Trigger.isbefore && (Trigger.isinsert || Trigger.isupdate)){
       accounthandler.DuplicateAccName(Trigger.new); 
}
```

Comment: Please review [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5) and [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) about Duplicate management: you could achieve this result via matching and duplicate rules. By the way, you should exclude the records in trigger context from the query (in before update you'll retrieve the records in scope if you update just any other field without changing name, leading to a wrong error).

Answer (score 0):

The `addError()` Method is being used in the wrong records causing the error.

> The `addError()` method is used on `Trigger.new` records in `insert` and `update` triggers, and on `Trigger.old` records in `delete` triggers, Not on the SOQL records.

please check [Trigger Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm) in **Apex Developer Guide** it will help.